# How to make a hotkey "press a key to set" system in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Since the title might be a bit vague, I'll try my best to explain it here.

Basically, I want a keybind system in my Tkinter application, in such a way that I click a widget that listens for my keyboard for a single character that this keybind would be set to. For example: like how you could go into the settings section of a game and change movement keys to what you prefer, change keybinds on photoshop to select the brush tool, etc.

Such example would be:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to keypresses with the .bind_all("<Key>", function) method. The function should have one parameter: event (if you are using classes use as parameter self and event). Then you can just check if you are setting your hotkey and save it in a variable (e.g. hotkey). All left to do is change the label to str(hotkey) so it will show the name of the key. Here is a example code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

changing = False

def hotkeyChange ():
    global changing
    changing = True
    changeBtn.configure(text = "press a key", state = DISABLED)

changeBtn = Button(root, text = "change Hotkey", command = hotkeyChange)
changeBtn.pack()

lbl = Label(root, text = "No Hotkey")
lbl.pack()

hotkey = None


def changeHotkey(event):
    global hotkey
    global changing
    if changing:
        hotkey = event.keysym
        lbl.configure(text = str(hotkey))
        changeBtn.configure(state = NORMAL, text = "change Hotkey")
        changing = False
    elif event.keysym == hotkey:
        print("Hotkey was pressed")
root.bind_all("<Key>", changeHotkey)
root.mainloop()
```

NOTE: I used spaces because i don't know how to format it in stackoverflow. So if you are using tabs, replace my spaces with them.